# Why is there no interface for SqlDataReader.ReadAsync()

Tags: c#, sql, async-await

While [`SqlDataReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the `IDataReader.Read()`, there appears to no interface for `SqlDataReader` when using the async methods like [`ReadAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

Firstly, correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there a reason or justification for this? Is there something about the new async-await stuff that justifies lacking an interface here? It's just a bit baffling.

Comment: The part of "SQL team not understanding OOP" is a very bold statement anyway :\

Comment: @MatiaszFidemraizer Yeah, shouldn't have said that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While the interface doesn't define the whole method, there's a common abstract class [`DbDataReader` which defines `ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Probably the most important reason to not include `ReadAsync` as part of `IDataReader` interface is to avoid a breaking change in terms of backwards compatibility.

If `IDataReader` in newer framework versions would force any *data reader*  to implement `ReadAsync`, any ADO.NET provider or framework relying on the so-called interface wouldn't be implementing it at all and these implementation would be broken.

Maybe they could use *interface segregation principle* and they could define a new interface called `IDataReaderAsync` which could provide asynchronous flavors of regular `IDataReader` members... But, at least, they've already provided a base class which is already derived by many framework classes:

> System.Data.DataTableReader
>
> System.Data.EntityClient.EntityDataReader
>
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
>
> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

...and third-party ADO.NET providers' `IDataReader` might also derive `DbDataReader`.